# Not able to connect to Oracle DB using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to connect to Oracle Database, using Excel VBA, but not able to connect. Any guidance is welcome.

```
Sub connection()

Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

constr = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<HostName>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<sid>))); uid=<UserName>; pwd=<Password>;"

cn.Open (constr)

End Sub
```

When trying to debug, it's giving the below error at Open Connection.

Automation Error
Unspecified Error

[Error While Creating the Database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aef1k.png)

Comment: Are you on a Mac (you tagged the question with *macos*). Is the driver present there?

Comment: No, I am using Windows.

Comment: Have you set all properties (hostname, port, sid, username, password) correctly? Can you connect to the database with other tools (SQL developer, SQL Plus, Toad...)?

Comment: @FunThomas yes all the properties are set correctly. I am able to connect to the database directly via SQL Developer. Also remotely I am able to connect to the database using PYTHON code from the same windows machine. So connection string is not having any problem.

Comment: Do the 32/64 bit versions match? Is your Office 32 or 64 bit? What about Oracle?